# Massive Online Analysis Framework- Split criteria

Tags: classification, weka, data-mining, moa

Am totally new to MOA. Am building VFDT classifier for certain number of instances(1000,10000,100000 and so on from a ArffFileStream). First, Am trying to use a learn model for the instances. Can anyone please tell me where can i find the split criteria and the attributes used for split from the model description. Below is the screenshot of the model description after learning 1000 instances.

[image]

Also, will i get any plot for the learn model. Because, am getting plot only for the evaluation prequential for accuracy whereas there is no plot for learn model.

Also, how can i import my arfffilestream to an excel sheet using  MOA?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: MOA is really only for simulation. There is no use in using an excel sheet. Also, why don't you direct your question to the MOA mailing list? That is where the MOA experts are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MOA is for stream simulation, so you'll get only the progression against time on kappa/accuracy/ram/cpu. However, if you want ROC and many details or graphics on the learn model you should use MOA classifiers through Weka there is a dedicated wrapper.

PS: the split criteria is an input parameter (-S).